# HTML5 JavaScript counting script not working

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

Not really sure why my script isn't working I don't see any errors, if anyone could give me some insight as to what is going wrong that would be great. 
I am not sure if the bootstrap is interfering because i can get it to work in plain html with no css or bootstrap applied to it.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>Pizza Menue</title>
            <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">   </head>
        <body>  
            <div class="container">
                <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid bg-danger">
                    <div class="container align-center">
                        <h1 class="display-2 text-center bold"><p class="text-light">Pure Pizza</p></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <button type="button" id="btnorder" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block btn-danger" onclick="getReceipt()">Place Order By Clicking Here!</button>
                </div>
                <div class="container m-3">
                    <h3>Pizza Size</h3>
                    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
                            <input class="size" type="radio" name="size" value="Personal Pizza" autocomplete="off" checked>Personal Pizza
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                            <input class="size" type="radio" name="size" value="Medium Pizza" autocomplete="off">Medium Pizza
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                            <input class="size" type="radio" name="size" value="Large Pizza" autocomplete="off">Large Pizza
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                            <input class="size" type="radio" name="size" value="Extra Large Pizza" autocomplete="off">Extra Large Pizza
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                            <div class="container m-3">
                                <h3>Meats</h3>
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <label class="form-check-label">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="meats" value="Pepperoni">
                                    Pepperoni
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <label class="form-check-label">
                                    <input class="form-check-input meats" type="checkbox" name="meats" value="Canadina Bacon" >
                                    Canadian Baon
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <label class="form-check-label">
                                    <input class="form-check-input meats" type="checkbox" name="meats" value="Ground Beef">
                                    Ground Beef
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check ">
                                    <label class="form-check-label">
                                    <input class="form-check-input meats" type="checkbox" name="meats" value="Anchovy" >
                                    Anchovies
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check ">
                                    <label class="form-check-label">
                                    <input class="form-check-input meats" type="checkbox" name="meats" value="Chicken" >
                                    Chicken
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check ">
                                    <label class="form-check-label">
                                    <input class="form-check-input meats" type="checkbox" name="meats" value="Sausage" >
                                    Sausage
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div id="showText"></div>
                    <div id="totalPrice"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script src="./js/js.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the scrip that goes along with the html, i have triple checked that it is linked correctly and everything is spelled correctly, so i am at a loss here cant figure out whats going on.

```
    function getReceipt() {
        var text1 = "<h3>You Ordered:</h3>;
        var runningTotal = 0;
        var sizeTotal = 0;
        var sizeArray = document.getElementsByClassName("size");
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < sizeArray.length; i++) {
            if (sizeArray[i].checked) {
                var selectedSize = sizeArray[i].value;
                text1 = text1+selectedSize+"<br>";
            }
        }
        if (selectedSize === "Personal Pizza") {
            sizeTotal = 6;
        } else if (selectedSize === "Medium Pizza") {
            sizeTotal = 10;
        } else if (selectedSize === "Large Pizza") {
            sizeTotal = 14;
        } else if (selectedSize === "Extra Large Pizza") {
            sizeTotal = 16;
        } 
        runningTotal = sizeTotal;
        console.log(selectedSize+" = $"+sizeTotal+".00");
        console.log("size text1: "+text1);
        console.log("subtotal: $"+runningTotal+".00");
        getMeat(runningTotal,text1); // All three of these variables will be passed on to each function
    };


    function getMeat(runningTotal,text1) {
        var meatTotal = 0;
        var selectedMeat = [];
        var meatArray = document.getElementsByClassName("meats");
        for (var j = 0; j < meatArray.length; j++) {
    if (meatArray[j].checked) {
        selectedMeat.push(meatArray[j].value);
        console.log("selected meat item: ("+meatArray[j].value+")");
        text1 = text1+meatArray[j].value+"<br>";
        }
    }
    var meatCount = selectedMeat.length;
        if (meatCount > 1) {
            meatTotal = (meatCount - 1);
            } else {
            meatTotal = 0;
        }
```

Comment: Look at the formatted, highlighted code in your post . . . missing anything? (Any console errors logged?)

Comment: What does " isn't working" mean? Be specific. Read this please: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `text` variable string doesn't have a closing double quote.

Change:
`var text1 = "<h3>You Ordered:</h3>;`

To:
`var text1 = "<h3>You Ordered:</h3>";`

Answer (score 0):

Edit your JavaScript. Add the missing double-quote (`"`) on line 2 and move the closing curly brace (`}`) on line 6 to the very bottom of the script.

```js
function getReceipt() {
    var text1 = "<h3>You Ordered:</h3>"; // <-- add this "
    var runningTotal = 0;
    var sizeTotal = 0;
    var sizeArray = document.getElementsByClassName("size");
    //}  <-- delete this }
    for (var i = 0; i < sizeArray.length; i++) {
        if (sizeArray[i].checked) {
            var selectedSize = sizeArray[i].value;
            text1 = text1 + selectedSize + "<br>";
        }
    }
    if (selectedSize === "Personal Pizza") {
        sizeTotal = 6;
    } else if (selectedSize === "Medium Pizza") {
        sizeTotal = 10;
    } else if (selectedSize === "Large Pizza") {
        sizeTotal = 14;
    } else if (selectedSize === "Extra Large Pizza") {
        sizeTotal = 16;
    }
    runningTotal = sizeTotal;
    console.log(selectedSize + " = $" + sizeTotal + ".00");
    console.log("size text1: " + text1);
    console.log("subtotal: $" + runningTotal + ".00");
    getMeat(runningTotal, text1); // All three of these variables will be passed on to each function
};


function getMeat(runningTotal, text1) {
    var meatTotal = 0;
    var selectedMeat = [];
    var meatArray = document.getElementsByClassName("meats");
    for (var j = 0; j < meatArray.length; j++) {
        if (meatArray[j].checked) {
            selectedMeat.push(meatArray[j].value);
            console.log("selected meat item: (" + meatArray[j].value + ")");
            text1 = text1 + meatArray[j].value + "<br>";
        }
    }
    var meatCount = selectedMeat.length;
    if (meatCount > 1) {
        meatTotal = (meatCount - 1);
    } else {
        meatTotal = 0;
    }
} // <-- add this }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>Pizza Menue</title>
            <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">   </head>
        <body>  
            <div class="container">
                <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid bg-danger">
                    <div class="container align-center">
                        <h1 class="display-2 text-center bold"><p class="text-light">Pure Pizza</p></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <button type="button" id="btnorder" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block btn-danger" onclick="getReceipt()">Place Order By Clicking Here!</button>
                </div>
                <div class="container m-3">
                    <h3>Pizza Size</h3>
                    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
                            <input class="size" type="radio" name="size" value="Personal Pizza" autocomplete="off" checked>Personal Pizza
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                            <input class="size" type="radio" name="size" value="Medium Pizza" autocomplete="off">Medium Pizza
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                            <input class="size" type="radio" name="size" value="Large Pizza" autocomplete="off">Large Pizza
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                            <input class="size" type="radio" name="size" value="Extra Large Pizza" autocomplete="off">Extra Large Pizza
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                            <div class="container m-3">
                                <h3>Meats</h3>
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <label class="form-check-label">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="meats" value="Pepperoni">
                                    Pepperoni
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <label class="form-check-label">
                                    <input class="form-check-input meats" type="checkbox" name="meats" value="Canadina Bacon" >
                                    Canadian Baon
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <label class="form-check-label">
                                    <input class="form-check-input meats" type="checkbox" name="meats" value="Ground Beef">
                                    Ground Beef
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check ">
                                    <label class="form-check-label">
                                    <input class="form-check-input meats" type="checkbox" name="meats" value="Anchovy" >
                                    Anchovies
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check ">
                                    <label class="form-check-label">
                                    <input class="form-check-input meats" type="checkbox" name="meats" value="Chicken" >
                                    Chicken
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check ">
                                    <label class="form-check-label">
                                    <input class="form-check-input meats" type="checkbox" name="meats" value="Sausage" >
                                    Sausage
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div id="showText"></div>
                    <div id="totalPrice"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script src="./js/js.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```